# Why is compiler considering this function non tail recursive?

Tags: ocaml, tail-recursion

I'm solving problems posted in [one of the OCaml tutorials](https://ocaml.org/problems). One of them is to write a function that will calculate the length of the list. It should be tail-recursive.

The naive, non tail-recursive solution is:

```ml
let rec length_naive xs  = (** Not tail recursive *)
  match xs with
  | [] -> 0
  | _ :: xs -> 1 + length_naive xs;;

(length_naive [@tailcall]) [1, 2, 3, 4];;

let one_hundred_million = 100000000;;
let non_tail_result = length_naive(List.init one_hundred_million (Fun.id));;
print_endline("Non-tail-recursive result: " ^ string_of_int(non_tail_result));;
```

Compiling and running this works exactly as expected. The warning (due to `@tailcall`) is printed, and the execution fails due to the stack getting overfown:

```
$ ocamlc lib/so.ml
File "lib/so.ml", line 14, characters 0-39:
14 | (length_naive [@tailcall]) [1, 2, 3, 4];;
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Warning 51 [wrong-tailcall-expectation]: expected tailcall

$ ./a.out
Fatal error: exception Stack_overflow
```

Now time for my attempt at writing a tail recursive version:

```ml
let length xs =
  let rec f xs len =
    match xs with
    | [] -> len
    | _ :: xs -> f xs (len + 1)
  in
  f xs 0;;

(length [@tailcall]) [1, 2, 3, 4];;

let one_hundred_million = 100000000;;
let tail_result = length(List.init one_hundred_million (Fun.id));;
print_endline("Tail recursive result: " ^ string_of_int(tail_result));;
```

Compiling and running it:

```
$ ocamlc lib/so.ml
File "lib/so.ml", line 15, characters 0-33:
15 | (length [@tailcall]) [1, 2, 3, 4];;
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Warning 51 [wrong-tailcall-expectation]: expected tailcall

$ ./a.out
Tail recursive result: 100000000
```

So it works, stack overflow exception didn't get thrown. However, compiler warns about the function not being tail recursive. My questions are:

- if this function is tail-recursive, why is compiler printing a warning?
- if this function is not tail-recursive, why is that?

I'm using OCaml compiler v 4.14.0.

Comment: Because it's the inner `f` and not the outer `length` that is actually recursive? (not being sarcastic, just curious)

Comment: Interesting. I moved `f` to the top-level (outside of `length`) and tried: `(f [@tailcall]) [1, 2, 3, 4] 0;;`. The warning was still printed though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A tail-recursive function and a tailcall optimizable (function) call are two different notions. Being `tail-call` is a property of function calls, whereas being `tail-recursive` is a property of functions.

In your example

```
length []
```

is a not tail-call optimizable call to a tail-recursive function.

It is the function calls inside the definition of `length` that are tail-call optimizable:

```
  let rec f xs len =
    match xs with
    | [] -> len
    | _ :: xs -> (f[@tailcall]) xs (len + 1)
```

More explicitly,

- A function call is tail-call optimizable when it is possible to reuse the current stack frame and thus avoid allocating a new stack frame. In particular, calls to recursive function inside the definition of the recursive function might reuse the parent call stack if it is possible to shortcut the return address.
- A function is tail-recursive when all calls to the function `f` in its body are tail-call optimizable.